# Minecraft Server save-all does not work as soon as expected?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, server-administration

Sorry in advance, this question could fall into 1 of 3 categories (server admin, gaming, or programming)

I'm working on a personal Minecraft server for my friends and I, I'm having the server back itself up on an interval, which requires the commands `save-all` and `save-off` to be called in succession before creating the backup file. (afterwards, `save-on` is called to put everything back to normal)

I'm monitoring the server's output/log to determine when the saving is off so I can create the backup. However, the server's response to my `save-off` command indicates it is ready, but when I go to make a backup, the world files are modified again, breaking my backup.

So far, my only solution is to add a delay between `save-off` and `backup`, but surely I'm either missing something or I can report this to Mojang so it can be handled a bit better. FWIW, I get the same behavior both on the latest stable version, as well as the latest snapshot.

Do `save-off` or `save-all` give any other sort of indication as to whether they are fully completed?

**NOTICE** I've created a bug-tracker [issue](https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MC-4417) with Mojang, we'll see what they have to say. :)

Comment: How do you send those commands to the server?

Comment: I'm writing to `stdin` for the `minecraft_server.jar` process

Comment: Did you try the save-off, then save-all order? That's what I'm using (with a 10 sec delay between save-all and the tar call, good enough for me).

Comment: `save-off` first? Hmm, I'll give that a try!

Comment: Fantastic! Calling `save-off` before `save-all` was exactly what I needed to do! Please add this as an answer so I can give you some rep. :)

Comment: @Maerlyn: Did you verify that it works like that? When I started writing Bukkit-Plugins (1.6 Beta...whoosh) `save-all` would do nothing if saving was disabled.

Comment: Oh... the log doesn't change one way or the other. (always says `Save complete.`)

Comment: The [startup script on the wiki](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Server_startup_script) uses `save-off` before `save-all`

Comment: @Bobby Yes, I had to restore from my backups a few times, when power failure corrupted the map.

Comment: Scratch that, I'm still getting that error trying to create my backup. Seems like "Save complete." is misleading. :(

Comment: is this backup being made with a script for linux or purely with minecraft server commands?

Answer (score 7):

You should call `save-off` first, `save-all` afterwards. This makes sure the world gets completely saved, and no save will occur during the creation of you backup.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting session.lock, as it's generated each time the world is loaded. If you are running a server, you must restart the server after deleting the session.lock file. If you're running Minecraft, you should re-log for the changes to take effect. By re-log I mean to exit to the title screen and then reload the world.

Answer (score -1):

Dominic, you were doing the right thing and in the correct order:

'save-all';
'save-off';
Wait some time (say, 30 seconds, or more);
Do the backup;
'save-on'

As far as I know, there is no way around the waiting. You either have to monitor the writing to the "world" directory by some filesystem event tool (inotify(7)) or wait for a fixed duration before backing up the data.

Doing 'save-off' first, as proposed by some here, is just wrong, as it disables the saving operations in 'save-all'; see e.g. http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/server-support/server-administration/1892430-save-off-breaks-save-all

In many cases you might not notice a difference, since the world is pretty frequently synced by auto-saving, anyway.